# Native Javascript scroll to bottom with smooth animation on div with dynamic added content

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scroll, native

I am making a chat app and what I want to archieve is when the dynamic messages are loaded in, that the page scrolls down with a smooth animation to the bottom of the div.

```
<ul id="messages">
                <li>
                    <p>Not logged in on Epic | Log in here: https://epic.clow.nl/login</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is not required for smooth scrolling. Try this -

```
window.scroll({
  top: 1000,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

This will jump the webpage down 1000px.

Comment: I would increase the top to a much higher number, to make sure it goes all the way down

Answer (score 0):

Okay second try now with native javascript.

There is this function.

```
window.scrollBy(0, 50);
```

This scrolls the windows down 50 every time its executed so you could maby make like a loop.

```
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
    }
```

And do something like

```
function smoothToBottom() {
    // change the time to make the ani go faster or slower
    var scrollTimer = setInterval(scrollDown, 200);
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
        clearInterval(scrollTimer);
    }
}

function scrollDown() {
   window.scrollBy(0, 10);
}
```

I havent tested this but it could work.

Answer (score -2):

You could achieve this very easily with jquery. Just add this to your `<head>`:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

And then add this to your javascript file:

```
function messagesAreLoaded() {
    $("div").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
}
```

This function needs to be called when the messages are loaded. The `<div>` element then gets scrolled to the bottom. Just make the `<div>` element whatever element needs to be scrolled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not allowed to use jquery only native javascript

Comment: Oh my bad hmm. I have a new plan