# Vue: Trigger event on automatic UI update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a v-for list of items that are based on list stored in Vuex. I want it so that the list automatically scrolls to the bottom every time a new item is added. I figured the scrolling part out using this: [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

The pseudocode is the following:

```
addItem(){
    dispatch vuex event to add item
    scroll to bottom of list
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that Vue seems to be updating the v-for list *after* the list is scrolled to the bottom, meaning that the list is always scrolled to the second to last item, instead of the last.

I fixed it by using a `setTimout()` to wait 10ms, but it feels a little hacky. Is there a better way to trigger the `scrollToBottom()` code on v-for list update?

Comment: `this.$nextTick(() => { /* scroll to bottom */ });` is the normal way to do it in Vue ([docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick))

Comment: That's the answer! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You have to separate the concerns. The update function simply updates the collection in the store. And inside a watch on the store getter (or mapState, whatever you have), you scroll the list to bottom. Also note that if you used commit instead of dispatch it would work, because dispatch is async while commit is sync. Another option would be to: `dispatch().then(() => scroll )`. -- dispatch returns a promise.

Comment: @tao, waiting for the dispatch to change the state is not enough. You need to wait for the next render. Example using `then` not working: https://jsfiddle.net/gLnqhvoe/1/ | Example using `$nextTick` working: https://jsfiddle.net/gLnqhvoe/

Comment: @blex can you submit your `$nexTick()` answer as a response so I can mark this as Solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to wait for the next render is to use [`this.$nextTick(() => /* ... */)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick). Here is a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  'store': new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      items: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
      index: 100
    },
    mutations: {
      itemAdded(state) {
        state.items.push(String.fromCharCode(++state.index));
      }
    },
    actions: {
      addItem({ commit }) {
        commit('itemAdded');
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['items'])
  },
  mounted() { this.scrollToBottom(); },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addItem');
      this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToBottom()); // <-------------------------
    },
    scrollToBottom() {
      this.$refs.list.scrollTop = this.$refs.list.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul { border: 1px solid black; height: 4em; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="addItem">Add item</button>
    <ul ref="list">
      <li v-for="(label, i) in items" :key="i">{{label}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need async / await dispatch;

```
async addItem(){
   await dispatch()
   scroll to bottom of list
}
```

Comment: No, waiting for the dispatch to change the state is not enough. You need to wait for the next render. Example using `async` not working: https://jsfiddle.net/gLnqhvoe/3/ | Example using `$nextTick` working: https://jsfiddle.net/gLnqhvoe/

Comment: @blex exactly why I think using `$nextTick()` is still the best answer. It's not posted as an actual response though, so I can't change this to solved

Comment: sorry, I wrong understood your question. you need catch after dom updated you can do nextTick or updated method. and Best solution as you said $nextTick()

// Life cycle method 'updated'
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

//$nextTick method
https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick