# bydefault scroll to the bottom of a div in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript

I used

```
var items = document.getElementById('messageBody');
items.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('messageBody').scrollHeight);
```

where,
'messageBody' is the id of the div with height 400px and vertical scroll in it.
This seems to be working fine in Chrome browser but its not working in Firefox.
Can someone help me with a fix for this issue in Firefox browser?

Comment: Searching your title I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

Comment: found this setTimeout(() => {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('div_id');
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight
}, 0).   This worked in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: So a timing issue. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var items = document.getElementById('messageBody');
items.scrollTop = items.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: That is what I already posted in the comment and in my answer

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work for Firefox

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, I also just tried some different solutions, but they all somehow don't work in Firefox...

Comment: It does. I just tested - see my answers

Comment: @mplungjan great job, I upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

From [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Works in Chrome 84 AND Firefox 80 AND 81

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("scroll");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
#scroll {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <div style="height:200px; background-color:red;">DIV 1</div>
  <div style="height:200px; background-color:blue;">DIV 2</div>
  <div style="height:20px; background-color:yellow;">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

ALSO Works in Chrome 84 AND Firefox 80 AND 81

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("scroll");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight - objDiv.clientHeight;
```

```css
#scroll {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <div style="height:200px; background-color:red;">DIV 1</div>
  <div style="height:2000px; background-color:blue;">DIV 2</div>
  <div style="height:20px; background-color:yellow;">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```