# Vue3 / Ionic: Auto Scroll down

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, chat, horizontal-scrolling

I am writing a VueJS App with Ionic. The App also has a Chat. Obviously, you want to see the lastest message, not the oldest one, so the app needs to open with the container scrolled to the bottom (also, every time you get a new message, you want it to appear at the bottom).

My HTML-Template (parts):

```html
  <ion-content
      :scroll-events="true">

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row v-for="(message, index) in messages" v-bind:key="index"
               :id="(index === messages.length-1)? 'bottomMessage': 'notLastMessage'">
        <ion-col
            size="9"
            :offset="message.fromUsrName === user.name ? 3 : 0 "
            :class="
            message.fromUsrName === user.name
              ? 'my-message'
              : 'other-message'
          "
        >
          <b>{{ message.fromUsrName }}</b
          ><br/>
          <span>{{ message.text }}</span>
          <div class="time">
            {{ new Date(message.timestamp).toLocaleString() }}
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
```

I tried the following:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('ion-grid')
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
```

```js
document.querySelector('ion-content').scrollToBottom(0);
```

```js
const messageDiv = document.getElementById('bottomMessage')
if (messageDiv) {
  messageDiv.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
} else {
  console.log("no messageDiv");
}
```

and the suggested answer here:
[Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

**EDIT:**
I also tried what 
[@Phil0xFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13147066/phil0xff) suggested:

```js
scrollToBottom: function () {
      console.log("scrollToBottom");
      const element = document.getElementById('content');
      if (element) {
        element.scrollToBottom(0);
        console.log("scrolled");
      } else {
        console.log("no div");
      }
    }
```

and the console shows the following:

```
scrollToBottom Chat.vue:171
scrolled Chat.vue:175
scrollToBottom Chat.vue:171
scrolled Chat.vue:175
```

**EDIT END**

None of that works, it refuses to scroll at all.
I also don't get any error message, I also verified, that the document.querySelector (and the  document.getElementById) actually find the element.

Since my data is loaded asynchronously, I also tried working with a timeout of 2 sec, to ensure that the data was loaded.

I would be grateful, if anyone has an idea on what I am missing or another great way of implementing my use case.

(I am starting to question my intelligence, this is quite a common use case, ain't it?)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error in my project, and after many hours of frustration have now found a solution.

It seems like the query selector has some kind of problems after routing over different pages. I was able to solve the error by giving the ion-content element an ID and using this ID for the selection of the element.

```
<ion-content id="content"></ion-content>

const element: any = document.getElementById('content');
element.scrollToBottom(0);
```

In a brand new project I could not reproduce the error, so I'm not sure if it's an Ionic issue.