# Set the default scroll to max

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way to set the default scroll of an element to the max always so when you append new element to it it will scroll by default to the max like this

```
#elmnt{
   default-scroll:max;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `default-scroll` in CSS. Do you mean `overflow: scroll` so that there will always be a scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

If you're **inserting child elements** into a parent container (like i.e: chat messages into a chat window), simply use [Element.scrollTo(*options*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```js
elChat.scrollTo({top: elChat.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth"});
```

Example:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


const elChat = el("#chat");
const addMessage = (textContent) => {
  const elMsg = elNew("div", {className: "message", textContent});
  elChat.append(elMsg);
  elChat.scrollTo({top: elChat.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth"});
};

let idx = 0;
el("#add").addEventListener("click", () => addMessage(++idx));
```

```css
#chat {
  background: #eee;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.message {
  background: gold;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">+ ADD</button>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

another suggestion: by using [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the added child element.

```js
elMessage.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

Example:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const elChat = el("#chat");
const addMessage = (textContent) => {
  const elMsg = elNew("div", {className: "message", textContent});
  elChat.append(elMsg);
  elMsg.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
};

let idx = 0;
el("#add").addEventListener("click", () => addMessage(++idx));
```

```css
#chat {
  background: #eee;
  height: 140px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.message {
  background: gold;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">+ ADD</button>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Notice in the last example how every ancestor is scrolled in order for the message to get into view.

Comment: thanks but the problem is when I add an element afterbegin

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually scroll to the bottom after the element has been appended.

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)