How to auto scroll when a new message pops up and not send an empty message?
I'm building an AI chatbot and I'm using tailwind to integrate css in my jsx file. I've been stuck on how to make the app scroll down automatically whenever a new message is sent or recieved. I want it so that if i scrolled up while waiting for the bot to respond it drops me down to see the response immediately. I also want it so that it doesn't send a blank message.
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

function ChatMessage( {message, type}) {
  return(
    <div className={`flex w-full ${type == "send" ?  "justify-end" : "justify-start"}`}>
      {type == "send" ? (
        <div className="bg-green-300 p-2 m-3 rounded-b-xl rounded-tl-xl shadow-md" >
          {message}
          </div>
      ) : ( 
        <div className="bg-gray-300 p-2 m-3 rounded-b-xl rounded-tr-xl shadow-md" >
        {message}
        </div>
      )}

      
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [input_message, setInputMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io("http://localhost:8080"); // Ensure this is the correct server endpoint
    setSocket(newSocket);

    newSocket.on("response", (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [
        ...prevMessages,
        {
          type: "recieve",
          message,
        },
      ]);
    });

    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = ($event) => {
    if($event.key !== "Enter") return;
    if (socket) {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [
        ...prevMessages,
        {
          type: "send",
          message: input_message,
        },
      ]);
      socket.emit("message", input_message);
      setInputMessage(""); // Clear the input field after sending the message
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-5 h-screen bg-gradient-to-b from-green-950 to-green-200">
      <div className="container mx-auto bg-blend-screen opacity-90 h-full flex flex-col">
        <div className="flex-grow p-3 flex flex-col items-end overflow-auto">
          <div className="w-full">
            {messages.map((message, index) => (
              <ChatMessage key={index} message={message.message} type={message.type} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="h-[100px] p-3 flex justify-center items-center bg-green-700 opacity-65">
          <input
            onKeyDown={sendMessage}
            value={input_message}
            onChange={(e) => setInputMessage(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Ask me anything...."
            type="text"
            className="w-full p-2 bg-transparent text-white border-white border-2 rounded-md outline-none"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} className="bg-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md mx-2 cursor-pointer">
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


I tried adding h-full in before overflow-auto but that doesn't work.

Maybe you can use this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div

You could write a hook that automatically scrollsIntoView.
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useScrollIntoView(behavior = "instant") {
    const ref = useRef(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) {
            ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: behavior });
        }
    }, [ref.current]);

    return ref;
};


function ChatMessage( {message, type}) {
      const scrollRef = useScrollIntoView();

      return(
        <div ref={scrollRef} className={`flex w-full ${type == "send" ?  "justify-end" : "justify-start"}`}>
          {type == "send" ? (
            <div className="bg-green-300 p-2 m-3 rounded-b-xl rounded-tl-xl shadow-md" >
              {message}
              </div>
          ) : ( 
            <div className="bg-gray-300 p-2 m-3 rounded-b-xl rounded-tr-xl shadow-md" >
            {message}
            </div>
          )}
    
          
        </div>
      )
    }

